# Possible to cast to interface that isn't inherited?

Tags: c#

Why isn't it possible to cast an instance of:

```
sealed class Foo
{
    public void Go() { }
}
```

...to this interface:

```
interface IBar
{
    void Go();
}
```

...even though `Foo` has the signature of `IBar`?

How can I turn an instance of `Foo` into an `IBar`? Assume I have no control over `Foo`.

Comment: "Assume I have no control over Foo" Then it's not an `IBar` and you can't cast it. You could _wrap_ it in a different clas that _does_ implement `IBar` but you can't cast it.

Comment: This is called _structural typing_ and some languages do in fact support this - TypeScript to name one which was designed by some of the same people.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, C# does not support duck-typing.

The OOP-approach to this problem is to use [the Adapter Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

You would do this:

```
class FooBarAdapter : IBar {

    private readonly Foo foo;

    public FooBarAdapter(Foo foo) {

        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void Go() {

        this.foo.Go();
    }
}
```

Whenever you have a `Foo` but need an `IBar` you wrap it on-demand:

```
public void ContrivedScenario() {

    Foo foo = GetFooFromExternalDependency();

    FooBarAdapter adapter = new FooBarAdapter( foo );

    this.NeedsIBar( adapter );
}

public void NeedsIBar(IBar bar) { ... }
```

I note that if `Foo`-to-`IBar` conversion happens a lot, you can make use of implicit conversions, so you don't need to explicitly construct `FooBarAdapter` instances, but it is debatable if this is good software engineering practice or not:

```
class FooBarAdapter : IBar {

    // (same as above)

    public static implicit operator FooBarAdapter(Foo foo) {
        return new FooBarAdapter( foo );
    }
}
```

That way you can do this:

```
public void ContrivedScenario() {

    Foo foo = GetFooFromExternalDependency();

    this.NeedsIBar( foo ); // the conversion from `Foo foo` to `FooBarAdapter` happens implicitly
}
```

One reason why C# doesn't support duck-typing is because just because a class's interface (in the OOP sense, not a literal `interface`) shares the same identifiers as another, doesn't mean they're compatible. For example `Process.Kill` (kills the process) and `MegaDeathKillBot3000.Kill` (kills all humanity) probably shouldn't be used interchangeably... unless you *really* want to.

Comment: An excellent answer but I would like to thank you particularly for the `MegaDeathKillBot3000` example. Or really just for the existence of `MegaDeathKillBot3000`. :)

Answer (score 3):

C# doesn't have "duck typing". In order for you to cast an instance from one type to another, they must have an inheritance relationship or have a custom cast overload defined. In this case though, you could have create a simple subclass for Foo like this if Foo weren't sealed:

```
class SubFoo : Foo, IBar {
    void Go()
    {
        base.Go();
    }
}
```

But since Foo itself is sealed, this is not possible, so instead you have to use containment like this.

```
class ContainsFoo : IBar 
{
     ContainsFoo(Foo foo)
     {
         this.foo = foo;
     }

     void Go() 
     {
         this.foo.Go();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [@Dai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39782761/323924), an alternative is using [a mock framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/), if you want to do your foo-bar cast in a test project.

```
var bar = Mock.Of<IBar>();
Mock.Get(bar).Setup(b => b.Go()).Callback(() => foo.Go());

MethodThatNeedsIBar(bar);
```

The framework creates a proxy of type `IBar` to `foo`, working like an adapter, but it's easier to setup and less code.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [Impromptu-Interface](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface) package which handles the wrapped duck-typing for you. It's a well established framework with multiple options including the ability to handle collections.